# Conceptual question about estimators

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

A random number generator produces uniformly distributed random numbers on the intervall $[0,a]$ where $a>0$ is unknown. We can draw $n$ independent $\mathcal U_{[0,a]}$ random numbers $X_1,...,X_n$ for the estimation. Find a mathematical formulation for the following estimators and check if they are biased and consistent.

1. "Twice the arithmetic mean of the observations"
2. "The maximum of the observations"

We just started estimators and I am having difficulties getting to the mathematical formulation and showing if they are consistent/bias.

**My attempt:**

*The definitions:*

- An estimator is unbiased if $E[\hat\theta_n]=\theta$
- An estimator is consistent if $\forall\epsilon>0$, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\Pr(\vert\hat \theta_n-\theta \vert>\epsilon)\to0$

*Calculations:*

1. Based on the hint and answer from Milten I want to estimate $\alpha. $Let $\hat\theta=2\bar{X}_n$ then:

$$\begin{split} \implies E[\hat \theta]-\alpha&= E[2\bar{X}_n]-\alpha\\&=E\left[\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right]-\alpha\\ &=\frac{2}{n} \sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i]-\alpha \\ &= \frac
{2}{n}n \frac{\alpha}{2}-\alpha \\ &=\alpha-\alpha=0\checkmark \end{split}$$

**My question:**

I don't understand what  $\theta$ is supposed to be here. Am I trying to estimate twice the mean with the sample I have drawn? Or is $\theta$ supposed to be the mean? More generally, I don't quite get the relationship between $\hat \theta$ and $\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$\theta$ is the parameter we wish to estimate (i.e. the true, unknown value), and $\hat \theta$ is the estimator, i.e. the approximation of the parameter. In your case $\hat \theta$ will be the two estimators given.

So what paramter in the set-up do you think the two estimators will approximate?

Example: Say $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ were i.i.d. Bernoulli distributed with $P(X_i=1)=p$. Then the observed mean would be an estimator for $p$, and it would be unbiased since $E(\bar X)=p$. So here $\theta=p$ and $\hat\theta=\bar X$.

EDIT: I'll add a bit about esimators in general. There are often several possible choices of estimators for the same parameter, like in this problem. Another common example is uncorrected/biased sample variance (which is an MLE) versus corrected/unbiased sample variance. *In theory* you could declare any function $(\mathbb R_{\ge0})^n \to \mathbb R_{\ge0}$ an estimator for $\alpha$ (e.g. you could always guess $\alpha=0$), but we of course want estimators that approximate the parameter in some sense. Hence the special names for unbiased/consistent/etc. estimators.

For consistency, Chebyshev or Law of Large Numbers (if you have it available) will work for the first estimator. For the second one, I'd calculate
$$
P(|\alpha - \max(X_i)| > \varepsilon) = P(\max(X_i) < \alpha - \varepsilon)
$$
directly.

Comment: Maybe I want to estimate the unknown $\alpha$? Is this just an exercise in checking if the estimators I am given are actually suitable for estimating $\alpha$?

Comment: That sounds good. Do you have reason to think the estimators will be close to $a$? Try to finish your calculation of $E(2\bar X)$. You're nearly there, you just need to plug in the value of $E(X_i)$.

Comment: I edited my question to include the new calculation. I am not sure about the fourth line of the calculation where I said $\sum_{i=1}^n E[X]_i=\frac{\alpha}{2}$ but the calculation seems to work out. Conceptually it makes sense to me that a uniform distribution of "width" $[0,\alpha]$ has a mean of $\frac{\alpha}{2}$ so by using twice the mean I would expect to get $\alpha$.

Comment: Yes, your calculation and intuition checks out :) If you need hints to some of the other three parts I can add some to my answer as requested

Comment: Nice! :) So the whole trick when it comes to estimators is 1) Identifying which quantity I want to estimate (for example mean, variance etc.) and then 2) finding and appropriate estimator that I can calculate from my sample values?

Comment: For the consistency. I am guessing applying the chebyshev inequality would be helpful there right?

Comment: Yes, that's the basic idea of estimators. I added a bit to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer really helped me :)